# How to Aggregate data to Graphite

Tags: python, node.js, installation, monitoring, graphite

I'm monitoring my node server with module [measured](https://github.com/felixge/node-measured), what I need is to aggregate the monitored stats to [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/start). This is getting me confused and frustrated. Trying to understand the Graphite guide be not going well at all, it's show a unix world command guide, im using windows. Trying to install the required components, but python command says no commands supported. Anyone has a good guide that is easily understand and supported for windows, much appreciated!

Comment: While this does not help with your actual problem, i always find it very difficult to work with python under windows. So i would rather suggest why dont you install something like virtualbox, download a linux installation cd (for instance ubuntu) and give it a shot.

Comment: @Christian Thieme: well, its not actual python programming, its just passing data to Graphite by using python, should be able to do it in windows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about graphite on Windows, but it can be difficult to setup even on linux, so I wouldn't even try on Windows.  It's complicated in part because graphite is actually composed of a few components that work together.

The easiest way I've found to get started with graphite is download and use a virtual machine image that's already been built.  For example, there are some [vagrant images](http://warwickp.com/2012/03/vagrant-box-with-graphite-statsd-gdash-nginx) that have graphite and statsd already.

[Hosted graphite](http://www.hostedgraphite.com/) is another possiblity, but it's not terribly cheap depending on your data retention needs, and I'm not sure I understand the security model.

If you're willing to muddle through the installation, [here's a screencast](http://obfuscurity.com/2012/08/Screencast---Installing-Graphite-from-Source) showing step by step how to do so.  That [obfuscurity blog](http://obfuscurity.com/Tags/Graphite) is also very informative about graphite use in general.